# Update en sql server con resultado de consulta

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, sql-server-2008

Tengo el siguiente `select` con el que obtengo unos códigos

```
SELECT tat.CPROV
FROM TPROVEEDORES_AG_TEMP tat
WHERE tat.NPROV IN
(
    SELECT t.CPROV
    FROM TDOCUMENTAL t
);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que estoy buscando es como `reemplazar` los nombres de la tabla `TDOCUMENTAL` el campo `CPROV` por los del `resultado` del anterior `select`

> Aquí algunos ejemplos de lo que he intentado:

```
--Cambiar los nombres x por los codigos, cuyo nombre en TDOCUMENTAl coincida con TPROVEEDORES
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
UPDATE TDOCUMENTAL
  SET 
      TDOCUMENTAL.CPROV =
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
           tat.CPROV
    FROM TPROVEEDORES_AG_TEMP tat
    WHERE tat.NPROV IN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
               t.CPROV
        FROM TDOCUMENTAL t
    )
);

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
UPDATE TDOCUMENTAL
  SET 
      TDOCUMENTAL.CPROV =
(
    SELECT tat.CPROV
    FROM TPROVEEDORES_AG_TEMP tat
    WHERE tat.NPROV IN
    (
        SELECT t.CPROV
        FROM TDOCUMENTAL t WHERE T.CPROV = tat.NPROV
    )
);
   ROLLBACK


BEGIN TRANSACTION;
UPDATE TDOCUMENTAL
  SET 
      TDOCUMENTAL.CPROV = tat.CPROV
FROM TPROVEEDORES_AG_TEMP tat
WHERE tat.NPROV IN
(
    SELECT t.CPROV
    FROM TDOCUMENTAL t
         INNER JOIN TPROVEEDORES_AG_TEMP tat2 ON tat2.NPROV = t.CPROV
);
```

> Edición:

Esta es la tabla 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
En la `Columna resaltada` es la que deseo actualizar y reemplazar el nombre que esta actual por su equivalente en `id` el cual seria CPROV de la tabla `TPROVEEDORES` 
`Ejemplo:`

> *TECNOMECANICA HR SAS  reemplazarlo por 890890890*

Comment: Podrias poner un ejemplo mas claro de que datos queres reemplazar por cuales? y cual es la condicion de union entre los mismos?

Comment: Claro que si voy a editar la pregunta

Comment: la tabla tproveedores entonces tiene un campo id y un campo que conecta con cprov?

Comment: El campo que las conecta es CPROV, solo que se hizo mal la insercción de los datos y quedo el nombre en vez del codigo

Comment: id supongo es de tipo numerico.. y cprov en esta tabla tambien deberia serlo no?

Comment: No lo son porque son codigos que pueden incluir un caracter especial ejemplo codigo: 13-32-4344 entonces se dejo de tipo nvarchar

Comment: el id no es numerico? eso es raro...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99600/discussion-between-brian-velez-and-gbianchi).

Comment: En si es un tema de PL (language procedure), aunque no se como sea en SQL server

Answer (score 0):

Para llenar el campo solo debes encontrar el id necesario del otro lado.

```
Update TDOCUMENTAL
set 
    TDOCUMENTAL.CPROV =
    (select id from TPROVEEDORES t where t.CPROV = TDOCUMENTAL.cprov)
```

Esto, por cada registro de la tabla TDocumental, ira a buscar a la tabla TProveedores el que corresponda.

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma de ver el tema es planteando en primer lugar esta consulta:

```
SELECT  t.CPROV, tat.CPROV
    FROM TDOCUMENTAL T
    INNER JOIN PROVEEDORES_AG_TEMP tat
        ON tat.NPROV = t.CPROV
```

y si lo que buscas es reemplazar `t.CPROV` por `tat.CPROV`, es bastante simple, reconvertir la anterior en una consulta de actualización:

```
UPDATE  TDOCUMENTAL
    SET CPROV = tat.CPROV
    FROM TDOCUMENTAL T
    INNER JOIN PROVEEDORES_AG_TEMP tat
        ON tat.NPROV = t.CPROV
```